# Error when building Angular 2 on windows

Tags: angular

When i clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git and try to run the steps in their developer guide i get the following error when running `./build.sh` or any `./test.sh`:

```
./build.sh: line 15: C:\Users\something\Google: No such file or directory
```

This is whats on the 15th line in the .sh:

```
$(npm bin)/tsc -p ${TSCONFIG}
```

This has to have something to do with windows but i can't figure out what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.